# Grid control with both filters and a summary row for WinForms

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a DataGridView-derived or DataGridView-like grid for WinForms that shows both filters for each column and a summary row?

There is a [CodeProject FilterableDataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9947/DataGrid-with-built-in-filter-functionality) and a [CodeProject Summary DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51889/Summary-DataGridView), but they can't be mixed together because FilterableDataGrid inherits from the obsolete DataGrid, while the Summary DataGridView inherits from DataGridView, so I can't make one inherit from the other.

What I'd like is a control that has the functionlity of both.

Requirements:

- Winforms (not WPF).
- Show both filters and a summary row.

Preferred:

- Is free.
- Filters allow searching by text, and for numeric and datetime columns searching by more, less or a range, in addition to just enumerating values.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion GridGroupingControl](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/grid-grouping-control) for Windows Forms supports filters and summary rows (as well as other features such as sorting , grouping, nested tables etc.)

**Filtering**

GridGroupingControl provides support for filtering with normal Filterbar, dyanamic filter bar and Excel like filter.

1. FilterBar

[FilterBar](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/data-representation#filter-bar) provides support to select or type in the filter bar to filter the items from the filter drop down for the particular column.

2. Dynamic Filter

[Dynamic filter](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/data-representation#dynamic-filter) provides support for filtering the items with dynamic filter drop down options and typing on the dynamic filter bar with the implementation of GridDynamicFilter class for GridGroupingControl.

3. Excel like Filter

[GridExcelFilter](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/grid-helper-classes#optimized-gridexcelfilter) provides support for filtering the items like Excel support. It provides support for Text filter, Number filter, Date filter and Color filter.
GridExcelFilter might suit your requirement as it provides support for number filter and date filter.

[image: Grid filter]

**Summaries**

GridGroupingControl provides support for [summarizing the columns](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/summaries).

[image: Grid summary]

**Free License**

The whole suite of controls and libraries is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). Note: I work for Syncfusion.